# Simple recurrence relation in three dimensions

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form, catalan-numbers

I have the following recurrence relation:

$$f[i,j,k] = f[i-1,j,k] + f[i,j-1,k] + f[i,j,k-1],\quad \mbox{for } i \geq j+k,$$

starting with $f[0,0,0]=1$, for $i$, $j$, and $k$ non-negative.

Is there any way to find a closed form expression for $f[i,j,k]$?

Note that this basically is a three dimensional version of the Catalan triangle, for which $f[i,j] = f[i-1,j] + f[i,j-1]$, for $i \geq j$, starting with $f[0,0]=1$. For this, a closed form expression is known: $f[i,j] = \frac{(i+j)!(i-j+1)}{j!(i+1)!}$.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Is $f[i,j,k]$ defined when $i\lt j+k$?

Comment: I assume $f(i,j,k)=0$ if any of $i,j,k$ are negative, otherwise I don't see how you've defined $f(2,0,1)$ with this recursion

Comment: @Will: For consistency with [Catalan’s triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansTriangle.html) it has to be $0$ when $i<j+k$.

Comment: Indeed, I should have specified in the problem statement that $f[i,j,k]=0$ if any of $i,j,k$ are negative, and that $f[i,j,k]=0$ if $i<j+k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the constraint $i \geq j+k$ I got following formula (inspired by the [Fuss-Catalan tetrahedra](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.0906v1.pdf) formula page 10 and with my thanks to Brian M. Scott for pointing out my errancies...)  :
$$f[i,j,k]=\binom{i+1+j}{j} \binom{i+j+k}{k} \frac{i+1-j-k}{i+1+j}\ \ \text{for}\ i \geq j+k\ \ \text{and}\ \ 0\ \ \text{else}$$

plane $k=0$
$ 
\begin{array} {lllll|lllll}
1\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 2\\  
1 & 3 & 5 & 5\\
1 & 4 & 9 & 14 & 14\\
\end{array}
$

plane $k=1$
$ 
\begin{array} {l}
0\\
1 \\
2 & 4\\
3 & 10 & 15\\
4 & 18 & 42 & 56\\
5 & 28 & 84 & 168 & 210\\
\end{array}
$

plane $k=2$
$ 
\begin{array} {l}
0\\
0\\
2 \\
5 & 15\\
9 & 42 & 84\\
14 & 84 & 252 & 420\\
20 & 144 & 540 & 1320 & 1980\\
\end{array}
$

---

Without the $i \geq j+k$ constrains we get the simple : $$f[i,j,k]=\frac{(i+j+k)!}{i!j!k!}$$

That is the [Trinomial expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion) (extension of Pascal triangle in 3D : [Pascal tetrahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_pyramid)).

At least with the rules :

- $f[0,0,0]=1$
- $f[i,j,k]=0$ if $i<0$ or $j<0$ or $k<0$
- $f[i,j,k] = f[i-1,j,k] + f[i,j-1,k] + f[i,j,k-1]$ in the remaining cases

Comment: It’s not: $$\begin{align*}f[2,2,0]&=f[1,2,0]+f[2,1,0]\\&=0+f[1,1,0]+f[2,0,0]\\&=f[0,1,0]+f[1,0,0]+f[1,0,0]\\&=0+2f[0,0,0]\\&=2\;.\end{align*}$$ It would probably help to take a look at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansTriangle.html).

Comment: @Brian: $f[1,1,0]$ should appear 2 times in the second line (+2 contribution) and $f[0,2,0]=1$ is missing (+1). Another +1 is missing for a total of 6.

Comment: I made that mistake originally, too: $f[1,1,0]$ appears only once, because $f[1,2,0]=0$ and doesn’t split. That’s why I wrote the $0$ term explicitly.

Comment: @Brian: Sorry but I still don't get it. For me it's $f[0,2,0]=1$ + $f[1,1,0]=2$ (I don't consider the constraint $i\ge j+k$ but I'll admit that it's perhaps the problem here...)

Comment: That’s exactly the problem. The OP wasn’t really clear, but the statement that it’s a $3$-dimensional analogue of [Catalan’s triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansTriangle.html) strongly implies that $f[i,j,k]=0$ if $i<j+k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the formula and the reference to the Fuss-Catalan tetrahedra.

However, I expect the plane $k=1$ to become
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 \\
 1  \\
 2 & 4 \\
 3 & 10 & 15 &\\
 4 & 18 & 42 & 56
\end{array}
$$
as, e.g., 
$$
f[2,1,1] = f[1,1,1] + f[2,0,1] + f[2,1,0] = 0 + 2 + 2 = 4
$$
instead of 3.

The Fuss-Catalan tetrahedra has a slightly different recursion, with one extra term subtracted: 
$$f[i,j,k] = f[i-1,j,k]+f[i,j-1,k]+f[i,j,k-1] - f[i,j-1,k-1]$$
(see formula 2.1).

Maybe the proposed closed-form expression can be adapted for that, but I do not see how that could be done.

Comment: @Wav: you are right and I gave it another try (I merely added a $j$ in the second binomial). Please verify my third release!

Comment: Great, exactly the solution to the recursion I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Wav: you are welcome!